# C# Changing background color of an CustomFieldData event

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I've got an PivotDataGrid wich is working fine. Also added an CustomUnboundFieldData, but now i want to change the backgroundcolor of the cell according to the value in this field.

To change the color i use a customCellAppearance event. Only this event is fired after i manipulate the values in the unbound field data.

So my question basically is, how to change the background of a cell. Using the unbound field data event?

Below a snippet of the code

```
//create unbound field
PivotGridField unboundField = pivot.Control.Fields.Add("unboundDataField", FieldArea.FilterArea);
unboundField.UnboundType = FieldUnboundColumnType.String;

//fill unbound field with data
private void Control_CustomUnboundFieldData(object sender, PivotCustomFieldDataEventArgs e)
{         

    String myValue = Convert.ToString(e.GetListSourceColumnValue("sourceColumn"));              
    e.Value = myValue.Substring(6);
    e.Field.SummaryType = FieldSummaryType.Max;            
} 

//code to change appearance of different cells
private void Control_CustomCellAppearance(object sender, PivotCustomCellAppearanceEventArgs e)
{    
    if(e.Value != null)
    {
        e.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green; 
    }

}
```

Comment: And which line of your code is responsible for changing the color?

Comment: The function "Control_CustomCellAppearance" is responsible for that. I've added this function just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color according to the "original data", use the CreateDrillDownDataSource method.

With this method u can get the source column and change the background color of the cell according to the value that comes out of the method.

Below a code snippet:

```
    private void Control_CustomCellAppearance(object sender, PivotCustomCellAppearanceEventArgs e)
    {
         PivotDrillDownDataSource ds = e.CreateDrillDownDataSource();
         //get value from the original source according to the row index
         String myValue = Convert.ToString(ds.GetValue(e.RowIndex, "sourceColumn"));

         //backgroundcolor condition
         if(myValue.Containts("something"))
         {
            e.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green; 
         }
    }
```

For more information i refer to the devexpress website: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotCellBaseEventArgs_CreateDrillDownDataSourcetopic